# Angular application gives blank page in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

`Angular` application loads only in `Internet Explorer` browser versions, when Developer Tools(F12) sidebar is opened. There aren't any MDL components in use, so it is different from [this](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/5183) issue. I can't see any errors in console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand question,blank page will solve:

go to polyfills.ts and uncomment this imports

```
   import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
   import 'core-js/es6/object';
   import 'core-js/es6/function';
   import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';     //Uncommented to enable IE11
   import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
   import 'core-js/es6/number';
   import 'core-js/es6/math';
   import 'core-js/es6/string';
   import 'core-js/es6/date';
   import 'core-js/es6/array';
   import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
   import 'core-js/es6/map';
   import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
   import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Answer (score 3):

As of v3 of the core-js library, the `/es#` folders have been replaced by

- `/es`
- `/features`
- `/stable`
- `/proposal`
- `/stages/#`

So for basic "es6" imports, the Angular polyfill imports should look as follows:

```
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';
```